# How do I persist data between callbacks in Python Dash to make an alert?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a bunch of badges on my homepage whose colour indicates whether a background process is safely running or not. Using dcc.Interval, every 30 seconds a redis get command pulls information about those background processes, and accordingly updates the colour of those badges.
I am trying to make it so if one of those badges turn red, an alert noise to go off.
The difficulty I am having is in how to save the data of the current colours, so that next callback I can create the new list, compare to the old, and then update the old with the new for the next callback to use.

My callback that updates the badges is currently as follows:

```
    def initialise_callbacks(app):
        @app.callback(
            [Output("{}".format(file), "color") for file in files],
            [Input("live-update2", "n_intervals")],
        )
        def update_greeks(interval):

            # default to list of "danger"
            color_list = ["danger" for i in files]

            i = 0
            for file in files:
                update_time = conn.get("{}_update".format(file.upper())) #get status from database
                if update_time:
                    if update_time.isOld: 
                        color_list[i] = "success"
                    else:
                        color_list[i] = "danger"
                else:
                    color_list[i] = "danger"
            i = i + 1
            return color_list
```

How do I use/save my output, color_list, in a way that next callback I can create a new color_list and compare it with the state in the previous callback, and then keep this loop going?

I have tried using dcc.Store and State, but keep running into problems with using the same variables as inputs (to compare with the new values) and then wanting to output the values too (which breaks the function as you can't have the same variables as input and output.
One solution would be to run database get commands twice in two different callbacks, once to update the colours, another to compare and update the memory store, but ideally this can be done without extra database steps.

Comment: You are incorrect to say that you cannot have the same variable as an Input and Output of a callback. This is definitely a valid scenario: https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#circular-callbacks

Comment: I suggest you explore dcc.store (never used that Personal ly but could help): https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is an example of a simple Dash app using `dash.State` and `dash.dcc.Store` to dynamically (via `dash.dcc.Interval` callback triggering), *independently* keep track of both the most-recently updated state(s) *and* previous state(s) of [a] badge component(s) (e.g., [`dbc.Badge`](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/badge/)), respectively:

In other words, `dash.State` provides the updated state of the badge as input to a callback which is triggered by changes set by `dash.dcc.Interval`; and browser data caching is leveraged using `dash.dcc.Store` to store (and thus have available for comparison) the previous states.

```py
import random

import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from dash import Dash, Input, Output, State, callback, dcc, html
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate


badge_colors = [
    # "primary",
    # "secondary",
    "success",
    "warning",
    "danger",
    # "info",
    # "dark",
]

badges = html.Span(
    [
        dbc.Badge(
            f"Proc #{x+1}-{y}",
            id=f"Proc #{x+1}",
            color=f"{y}",
            className="me-1",
            style={"margin": "1%"},
        )
        for x, y in zip(range(len(badge_colors)), ["success"] * 3)
    ],
    id="badges",
)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        # The memory store reverts to the default on every page refresh
        dcc.Store(id="memory"),
        # The local store will take the initial data
        # only the first time the page is loaded
        # and keep it until it is cleared.
        dcc.Store(id="local", storage_type="local"),
        # Same as the local store but will lose the data
        # when the browser/tab closes.
        dcc.Store(id="session", storage_type="session"),
        html.Div(
            badges,
            id="badges-container",
            style={
                "margin-top": "5%",
                "position": "relative",
                "text-align": "center",
            },
        ),
        dcc.Interval(
            id="live-update2",
            interval=3 * 1000,  # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0,
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            [dbc.Alert("No updates received yet.", color="light")],
            id="update-alert",
            style={"text-align": "center",},
        ),
    ]
)


@callback(
    [
        Output("badges", "children"),
        Output("update-alert", "children"),
        Output("session", "data"),
    ],
    [
        Input("live-update2", "n_intervals")
    ],
    [
        State("badges", "children"), 
        State("session", "data")
    ],
)
def update_badges(interval, badges, session_cache):
    if interval < 1:
        print(badges) # Used for debug to see dbc data structure
        raise PreventUpdate
    # Initialize the local cache on first interval callback trigger
    if interval == 1:
        data = {b["props"]["id"]: b["props"]["color"] for b in badges}
        alert = (
            dbc.Alert(
                "Session cache initialized. No updates yet.", color="info"
            ),
        )
        return [badges, alert, data]
    else:
        # Replace code below w/ custom badge status update:
        updated_badges = [
            dbc.Badge(
                f"{x}-{y}",
                id=x,
                color=f"{y}",
                className="me-1",
                style={"margin": "1%"},
            )
            for x, y in zip(
                [b["props"]["id"] for b in badges],
                random.choices(badge_colors, k=len(badges)),
            )
        ]

        # Check if any of the updated badges have changed from "success"
        # (or "warning") to "danger". If so, flag sudden_danger and report
        # which processes have returned a failure signal in latest update
        # triggering this callback.
        #
        # Also update the local cache with the updated processes statuses
        # (i.e., the badge colors).
        sudden_danger = False
        alerts = []
        for b in updated_badges:
            prev_color = session_cache[b.id]
            if b.color == "danger" and prev_color != "danger":
                sudden_danger = True
                alerts.append(b.id)

        if sudden_danger:
            alert = dbc.Alert(
                f"ALERT: The following process(es) returned a new failure signal: {alerts}",
                color="danger",
            )
        else:
            alert = dbc.Alert(
                "No dangerous changes in badges.", color="success"
            )

        data = {b.id: b.color for b in updated_badges}
        return [updated_badges, alert, data]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

which yields, for example:
[image: live demo]

### Additional Details

In the provided code above, I simulated your redis db connection updating by simply generating randomly selected statuses (from the possible set including ['Success', 'Danger', 'Warning']). Whenever any of three "process" badges change from a non-danger status to danger, then, the alert is triggered, as shown.

- #### `dash.State` is used for accessing data as an input to a callback; changes to a state input do not trigger the callback

(vs. `dash.Input`, which *will* trigger a callback whenever changed [in this case, e.g., `dash.dcc.Interval`])

- #### `dash.dcc.Store` stores data in the browser's cache, which can be directly examined live e.g. using Chrome Dev Tools

(as shown above in GIF recording of live web app when running)

---

*Note:
I chose to use the ["session" storage type](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store#store-properties) in this example,
but you may find choosing one of the other two options ("memory", or "local") better suits your use case (see linked docs & code comments for more about using `dash.dcc.Store`).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Hope it helps :)

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input, State

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Interval("clock"),
    dcc.Store("state"),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("state", "data"),
    State("state", "data"),
    Input("clock", "n_intervals")
)
def update(data, interval):
    print(f"Current data: {interval}")
    print(f"Stored data: {data}")
    return interval

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```